# Gauge transformation in Background Field Gauge, Weinberg Section 17.4, QFT 2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization

Whole idea of using background field method is to keep explicit gauge invariance, which is useful during renormalization.

In section 17.4, background field gauge, Weinberg defines a `formal` transformation on fields of a gauge theory in presence of a background field as:
\begin{align*}
        &\delta A_{\alpha}^{\mu} = \partial^\mu \epsilon_{\alpha} - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta} A_{\gamma}^{'\mu}\\
        &\delta A_{\alpha}^{'\mu} = - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma}\epsilon_\beta  A_{\gamma}^{'\mu}\\
        &\delta \psi = i t_{\alpha} \epsilon_{\alpha} \psi\\
        & \delta \psi' = i t_{\alpha} \epsilon_{\alpha} \psi'\\
        & \delta \omega_{\alpha} = - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta}\omega_{\gamma}\\
        & \delta \omega^{'}_{\alpha} = - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta}\omega^{'}_{\gamma}\\
        & \delta \omega^*_{\alpha} = - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta}\omega^*_{\gamma}\\
        & \delta \omega^{'*}_{\alpha} = - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta}\omega^{'*}_{\gamma}
\end{align*}
where primed fields are quantum fields and are integrated over in path integral, unprimed are background fields. While this formal transformation acts in the same way as gauge transformation acts on the sum of fields $A+A'$, $\psi+\psi'$ as can be seen from the definition, however, true gauge invariance acts as follows:

\begin{align*}
    &\delta_{TRUE} A^{\mu}_{\alpha} = 0,\\
    &\delta_{TRUE} A^{'\mu}_{\alpha} = \partial^\mu \epsilon_{\alpha} - C_{\alpha \beta \gamma} \epsilon_{\beta} (A_{\gamma}^{\mu}+A_{\gamma}^{'\mu})\\
    & = \bar{D}_{\mu} \epsilon_{\alpha} - C_{\alpha \beta\gamma}\epsilon_{\beta}A_{\gamma}^{'\mu}\\
    &\delta_{TRUE}\psi = 0\\
    &\delta_{TRUE}\psi' = i t_{\alpha}(\psi+\psi').
\end{align*}

I understand on the sum of the quantum and background field, both transformation should produce the same result, that's what aids us in defining this formal transformation, but I am not completely sure about the effect of true gauge invariance of background field and the quantum fields individually; please let me know if you understand this completely.